# Matlab how do I appy a ASDR Curve to get smoother sounds (Problem with the implementation)

Tags: matlab, audio, frequency, synthesizer, piano

So I want to apply a ADSR Curve for my tone function that uses different Amplitude values

In the function envel I have the function for my ADSR Curve Array

First off

I have problems do apply the values to my E Array

I want it to take 1/8 to reach 1 for my Attack phase

Any suggestions on how to accomplish the implementation are welcome thanks.

But my implementations don't work I have tried create a vector that has 1/8 Values of my sin wave

Tried to use this array for 1/8 Values of my E but I only get 0 as entries for the region of E

I have to use the parameters of the envel

```
sound(note(23, 1 / 2, 1, 8000));

function [sinusoid] = createWaveform(frequency, fs, duration, A)
    Fs = fs;     % samples per second
    dt = 1 / Fs; % seconds per sample
    t = (0:dt:duration)'; % seconds
    % %Sine wave:
    Fc = frequency; % hertz
    sinusoid = A .* cos(2 * pi * Fc * t + (2 * pi) .* rand(1, 1));
    % Plot the signal versus time:
end

function [tone] = note(keynum, relDuration, fullDuration, fs)
    basetone = 440;
    frequency = basetone * nthroot(2, 12) ^ (keynum - 49);
    tone = createWaveform(frequency, fs, relDuration * fullDuration, 1) .* envel(relDuration, fullDuration, fs);
end

% [E] = envel(relDuration,fullDuration,fs)

function [E] = envel(relDuration, fullDuration, fs)

    dt = 1 / fs;
    dr = fullDuration * relDuration;
    t = (0:dt:dr)';
    E = (0:dt:dr)';
    S = 0;
    a = 1 / 8 * length(t);
    f = linspace(0, 1, a);
    E(1:round(1 / 8 * length(t))) = f(1, :);

    X = 1; % Delay
    for i = round(length(t) * 1 / 8) : round(length(t) * 3 / 8)
        E(i) = X - 1 / 10 * (relDuration * fullDuration * fs * 1 / 8);
        X = E(i);
    end
    F = X; % Sustain
    for i = round(length(t) * 3 / 8) : round(length(t) * 6 / 8)
        E(i) = F;
    end
    Y = F; % Restain
    for i = round(length(t) * 6 / 8) : round(length(t) * 8 / 8)
        E(i) = Y - F / (relDuration * fullDuration * 1 / 8);
    end
    disp(E);
end
```

Comment: On second look at the given code there appears to be missing elements. I'd suggest to providing a simple, self-contained reproducible example. That said, ADSR will just be a case of **A**: linear ramp up to sample `A_n` to gain `A_g`, **D**: a linear ramp down to sample `D_n` to gain `D_g`, **S**: a duration of `S_n` at gain `D_g` and **R** a linear ramp down to `0` gain. After that you can consider doing a spline as opposed to a linear ramp.

Comment: Also, try plotting the output of `envel(0.5, 1, 8000)`, does that look like an ADSR envelope?

Comment: `E(i) = Y - F / (relDuration * fullDuration * 1 / 8);` makes very little sense as `Y`, `F`, `relDuration` and `fullDuration` are all constant

Comment: I would recommend that if `envel` is meant to generate an **ADSR** envelope, you should give it parameters **A**, **D**, **S** and **R**. i.e. `envel(Attack, Decay, Sustain, Release, SampleRate)`. `relDuration` and `fullDuration` do not make it immediately clear what it is you are trying to achieve.